# argpase requiring additional options if a specific option is selected

Tags: python, argparse

I have read many help links on this issue but none were EXACTLY like my situation so I decided to post here.  I am using argparse to grab some command line options.  The issue I am having is 1 flag is always required (-m) so I defined it as so

```
parser.add_argument('-m','--mode', type=str, required=True , metavar='<add|del|list|delID>', choices=['add', 'del' , 'list', 'delID'])
```

As you can see the only possible acceptable parameters are 'add', 'del', 'list' and delID'

What I need it to do is force 2 additional options to be required if a certain option is entered from the args.mode flag.  Here's what I have tried currently but the error is always being triggered

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Help Desk Calendar Tool')
parser.add_argument('-m','--mode', type=str, required=True , metavar='<add|del|list|delID>', choices=['add', 'del' , 'list', 'delID'])
parser.add_argument('-s', '--start', type=str, required=False, metavar='<Start date in the following format - YYYY-MM-DD>')
parser.add_argument('-e','--end', type=str, required=False, metavar='<End date in the following format - YYYY-MM-DD>')
parser.add_argument('-d','--delete', type=str, required=False, metavar='<Event ID Here>')

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.mode in ('add','del','list'):
    print args.mode
    if args.start is None or args.end is None:
        parser.error('Options add, del and list all require the start (-s) and end (-e) date to be set')

if args.mode in ('delID'):
    if args.start is not None or args.end is not None:
        parser.error('The option delID can ONLY except the event ID, no other options can be entered')

if args.mode in ('delID'):
    if args.delete is None:
        parser.error('The delete (-d) option is required when delID mode is selected')
```

So if I run `command.py -s 2016-02-11 -e 2016-02-16 -m add` the first error condition is still triggered.
Now it does work for the delID conditional checks.  Any suggestions?

Thanks

**Update**

Looks like the above does in fact work.  Turns out I had an additional error check in my definition that was throwing the error

```
    if mode in ('add','del','list'):
        parser.error("Options add,del and list all require a start (-s) and end (-e) date!")
```

Thanks for bringing it to my attention

Comment: `command.py -s 2016-02-11 -e 2016-02-16 -m add` works for me without any errors..please recheck.

Comment: What are the values of start and end when it errors?

Comment: OMG, I must have just been staring at the code for too long.  I had another error check later in my definition that was causing the error.  I updated the above.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Completed working code

```
def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Help Desk Calendar Tool')
    parser.add_argument('-m','--mode', type=str, required=True , metavar='<add|del|list|delID>', choices=['add', 'del' , 'list', 'delID'])
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--start', type=str, required=False, metavar='<Start date in the following format - YYYY-MM-DD>')
    parser.add_argument('-e','--end', type=str, required=False, metavar='<End date in the following format - YYYY-MM-DD>')
    parser.add_argument('-d','--delete', type=str, required=False, metavar='<Event ID Here>')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.mode in ['add','del','list']:
        if args.start is None or args.end is None:
            parser.error('Options add, del and list all require the start (-s) and end (-e) date to be set')

    if args.mode == 'delID':
        if args.start is not None or args.end is not None:
            parser.error('The option delID can ONLY except the event ID, no other options can be entered')

    if args.mode == 'delID':
        if args.delete is None:
            parser.error('The delete (-d) option is required when delID mode is selected')

    start = args.start
    end = args.end
    mode = args.mode
    event = args.delete

    return start,end,mode,event
```